# Помогите разобраться с JVS

Tags: javascript

Получаю ошибку jquery.min.js:2 GET net::ERR_FAILED

```
<input type="hidden" name="af_action" >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
              <script>

$("#phone-button").click(function() {
    phone = document.getElementById('phone_phone').value
    name = document.getElementById('name_name').value
    document.getElementById('phone-button').innerHTML = 'Отправляется...'
    $.get("https://taxigreenline.ru/phone/", {name:name, phone:phone})
        .done(function (data) {
            document.location.href = "https://taxigreenline.ru/yes/";
        });
});

$('#popup_bg, #popphone, #popup').hide("normal");

$('#tel').click(function(){

    $('#popup_bg, #popphone, #popup').show("normal");
})

$('#ghil').click(function(){

    $('#popup_bg, #popphone, #popup').show("normal");
})

$('.p_close').click(function(){

    $('#popup_bg, #popphone, #popup').hide("normal");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не объявляете переменные, а обращаетесь к существующим, которых по всей видимости нет.

```js
$("#phone-button").click(function() {
    const phone = document.getElementById('phone_phone').value
    const name = document.getElementById('name_name').value
    document.getElementById('phone-button').innerHTML = 'Отправляется...'
    $.get("https://taxigreenline.ru/phone/", {name, phone})
        .done(function (data) {
            document.location.href = "https://taxigreenline.ru/yes/";
        });
});
```